# Derivative of $\sup$ (with also an integral)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

How can I reduce the following expression

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sup_{y \in [a,b]}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x+z,x,y) dz$$

to something easier to calculate?

We know that $y \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x+z,x,y) dz$ is continuous and $F$ is continuous as a function of $x$ and $x+z$,

Comment: Without further assumptions, I don't think there is anything you can do. How does the problem arise? Perhaps there is an underlying question that is more tractable.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I'm interested in the question for itself. What kind of further assumptions do you think we need?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't think of any reasonable assumptions to apply.  Possibly some strict concavity assumption would ensure that the supremum is actually a maximum, which might move continuously or even smoothnly as $x$ is varied. But as stated, I think this is a problem much too open ended to be a good fit for the stackexchange format, which is primarily for questions having a definite answer.